How to extend upon siunitx to list units?
I have made this trivial additional macro using siunitx called \qtyalt{} and \numalt{} that helps me add the separator "or" at the end of the list like so:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}
\usepackage[mode=text]{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty = true}

% Defining \qtyalt macro
\newcommand{\qtyalt}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sisetup{
    list-final-separator = {, or },
    list-pair-separator = { or }
  }%
  \qtylist{#1}{#2}% Using the \qtylist format
  \endgroup
}

% Define \numalt macro
\newcommand{\numalt}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \sisetup{
    list-final-separator = {, or },
    list-pair-separator = { or }
  }%
  \numlist{#1}% Using the \numlist format
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}

Samples concentrations were either \qtyalt{10(1); 20(2); 30(1)}{\gram\per\litre}, and exposed radioactive material \numalt{1; 2; 3}.

\end{document}


That generates an output:

I am unable to use the same approach to create \unitlist{} and \unitalt{}. This is admittedly never really going to be robustly used everwhere, but it would be helpful in cases where I can write the sentence:
Be careful about units. Jumping systems results in their 0 values 
having very different meanings. For example, the zero value for 
\unitlist{\kelvin; \farenheit; \celcius} are not the same!.

or
Please express your answers in \unitalt{\milli\gram\per\litre;\molar}.

I know it is much easier to change the prose rather than play with macros. For example, one may argue that I need a macro for "or" and one for "nor" in case of negation. But this is just something I want to play with in LaTeX.

My attempt using expl3:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}
\usepackage[mode=text]{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty = true}

% Defining \qtyalt macro
\newcommand{\qtyalt}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sisetup{
    list-final-separator = {, or },
    list-pair-separator = { or }
  }%
  \qtylist{#1}{#2}% Using the \qtylist format
  \endgroup
}

% Define \numalt macro
\newcommand{\numalt}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \sisetup{
    list-final-separator = {, or },
    list-pair-separator = { or }
  }%
  \numlist{#1}% Using the \numlist format
  \endgroup
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l__index_int % un entier utilisé comme compteur
\cs_new_protected:Npn \formatUnits:n #1
{
  \int_zero:N \l__index_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn #1
  {
    \int_compare:nNnT {\l__index_int} > \c_zero_int 
    {
      \int_compare:nNnTF {\l__index_int} = {\seq_count:N #1 - 1}
      {\c_space_token or \c_space_token}{,\c_space_token}
    }
    \tl_if_blank:eF {##1}{\unit{##1}}
    \int_incr:N \l__index_int
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\unitlist}{m}
{
  \seq_clear_new:N \l__temp_seq % nouvelle seq temporaire vide
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__temp_seq { ; } { #1 } % découpe l'arg selon le séparateur « ; »
  \formatUnits:n \l__temp_seq % affiche la séquence
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  
  Samples concentrations were either \qtyalt{10(1); 20(2); 30(1)}{\gram\per\litre}, and exposed radioactive material \numalt{1; 2; 3}.
  
  Be careful about units. Jumping systems results in their 0 values 
  having very different meanings. For example, the zero value for 
  \unitlist{\kelvin; \degreeCelsius}
  are not the same!
  
\end{document}


